# Making anchor tag in a table clickable

Tags: jquery, html

Using jquery, I am trying to click elements in an anchor tag from an array reading from a database, but it doesn't seem to work, it's not doing anything

```
$("#download").click(function(){
       alert("inside onclick");
     })


html = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Surname</th><td><a href='#' class='download'>" + response.relatedplaces.where +  "</a></td></tr>" +  "<table>"
```

Comment: Nothing shown in html has an `id="download"`

Comment: First of all replace `class="download"` with `id="download"` then replace click event with `.on` event, something like this: `$(document).on('click', '#download', function() { .......... });`

Comment: @Adeel thanks. that works

Comment: I'm glad I could help! @lloyd

Answer (score 0):

`$("#download")` is equivalent to js `getElementById`, BUT in your html you have `class='download'` which is a class, not an `id`.

Replace `$("#download")` to `$(".download")` or `class='download'` to `id='download'`

If i change `class='download'` to `id='download'` in your example it works :

```js
$("#download").click(function(){
       alert("inside onclick");
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>
<tr><th>Surname</th><td><a href='#' id='download'>something</a></td></tr>
<table>
```

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work. is it because I have 'html = ' before the table tag?

Comment: `html=...` is a string associated to  a variable named `html`. How do you use that variable ? In my example, I put the content of your variable in a .html file

Comment: the table is inside a modal and enclosed in a tab (this is where it is used) which opens once I click something. so I am now trying to click an an tag inside the table